# Does the Wolfram Cloud permit real-time Collaboration?

Tags: programming, wolfram-cloud, education

I am curious if anyone has found a workaround or directly built-in method to work collaboratively with colleagues? Something analogous to the google productivity apps like google docs where different people have color-coded identifiers, and everyone with access can make changes in real-time.

I am considering various applications to introduce middle school students to computational thinking ideas in a collaborative project-based learning activity and the Wolfram Cloud seems promising.

Comment: Nope.  Years ago there was a flirtation with 1-directional streaming and chat stuff in the desktop, but I think it was abandoned.